# Error while processing route: No model was found for - Ember.js Guides

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Learning Ember with Ember.js guides. While practicing ToDo application, I renamed model from `todo` to `tododata` but I get `Error while processing route: todos No model was found for 'tododata' Error: No model was found for 'tododata'})`.

Renaming model back to `todo` works fine.  Not sure what is wrong (except the fact there is CamelCase is being used).  Would appreciate some direcction

My setup:

Model: In guide `Todos.Todo` but I named it `Todos.TodoData` for clarity.

```
Todos.TodoData = DS.Model.extend({
...
});
```

Router: In guide `...find('todo');`, I use `...find('tododata');`

```
Todos.TodosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('tododata');
    }
});
```

Controller: In guide it was `todo`, mine is `tododata`

```
    Todos.TodosController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({    
        actions: {
        ...
                var todo = this.store.createRecord('tododata', {
                    ...
                });
        ...
        }
});
```

Using `TodoData` instead of `tododata` works fine but I am not sure if this is a correct usage (because my thinking is `tododata` is an instance of `TodoData`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to consider using camelCase when calling this.store for that model. There are two options to handle camelCase in this.store methods arguments:

1. this.store.find('todo_data');
2. this.store.find('todoData');

Ember uses [Ember.DefaultResolver](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.DefaultResolver.html) to find what you requested. You can override it's behavior if you need so (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.7.0/packages/ember-application/lib/system/resolver.js#L115).

Comment: Brilliant.  Works great. Will accept the answer shortly.